# Thread safe operations on XDP

Tags: ebpf, bpf, xdp-bpf, xdp-ebpf, libbpf

I was able to confirm from the documentation that bpf_map_update_elem is an atomic operation if done on HASH_MAPs. Source (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bpf.2.html). [Cite: map_update_elem() replaces existing elements atomically]

My question is 2 folds.

1. What if the element does not exist, is the map_update_elem still atomic?
2. Is the XDP operation bpf_map_delete_elem thread safe from User space program?

The map is a HASH_MAP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Atomic ops, race conditions and thread safety are sort of complex in eBPF, so I will make a broad answer since it is hard to judge from your question what your goals are.

Yes, both the `bpf_map_update_elem` command via the syscall and the helper function update the maps 'atmomically', which in this case means that if we go from value 'A' to value 'B' that the program always sees either 'A' or 'B' not some combination of the two(first bytes of 'B' and last bytes of 'A' for example). This is true for all map types. This holds true for all map modifying syscall commands(including `bpf_map_delete_elem`).

This however doesn't make race conditions impossible since the value of the map may have changed between a `map_lookup_elem` and the moment you update it.

What is also good to keep in mind is that the `map_lookup_elem` syscall command(userspace) works differently from the helper function(kernelspace). The syscall will always return a copy of the data which isn't mutable. But the helper function will return a pointer to the location in kernel memory where the map value is stored, and you can directly update the map value this way without using the `map_update_elem` helper. That is why you often see hash maps used like:

```c
value = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&hash_map, &key);
if (value) {
    __sync_fetch_and_add(&value->packets, 1);
    __sync_fetch_and_add(&value->bytes, skb->len);
} else {
    struct pair val = {1, skb->len};

    bpf_map_update_elem(&hash_map, &key, &val, BPF_ANY);
}
```

Note that in this [example](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17.6/source/samples/bpf/sockex2_kern.c), `__sync_fetch_and_add` is used to update parts of the map value. We need to do this since updating it like `value->packets++;` or `value->packets += 1` would result in a race condition. The `__sync_fetch_and_add` emits a atomic CPU instruction which in this case fetches, adds and writes back all in one instruction.

Also, in this example, the two struct fields are atomically updated, but not together, it is still possible for the `packets` to have incremented but `bytes` not yet. If you want to avoid this you need to use a spinlock(using the `bpf_spin_lock` and `bpf_spin_unlock` [helpers](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/bpf-helpers.7.html)).

Another way to sidestep the issue entirely is to use the `_PER_CPU` variants of maps, where you trade-off congestion/speed and memory use.

Comment: Had a follow up question. The use case is basically to use XDP's redirect functionality. Say we are getting packets from A to B, we need to redirect it to C. So in a way doing A->B->C. Now, say we no longer get packets from A, then I need to delete this entry from the map from the user space program, for which I am using map_delete_elem. But there can be several threads calling this function, and as per your answer, it should be ok right?

Comment: Yes, nothing bad is going to happen. The only thing is that your threads may get a `-ENOENT` as return value if the key doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Additional reference: under the hood, map updates are protected with [RCU](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/RCU/whatisRCU.html).