# How does __sync_fetch_and_add() work in bpf programs

Tags: race-condition, ebpf, bpf

I'm writing several bpf programs that will update the same counter which is implemented by a `BPF_MAP_TYPE_ARRAY` bpf map. To avoid data races, I referred the [bpf kernel doc](https://docs.kernel.org/bpf/map_array.html) and used the `__sync_fetch_and_add()` intrinsic. However, I'm confused about how `__sync_fetch_and_add()` works in bpf. I found in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72192140) that `__sync_fetch_and_add()` leverages atomic CPU instructions to implement atomic update, but ebpf source code written in C will be compiled into bpf bytecode, will these native atomic instructions be preserved in the bpf bytecode program after compilation? Or does the bpf instruction set also provide atomic instructions?

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, all of that is correct. The intrinsic will emit atomic instructions in eBPF byte code. The [kernels docs](https://docs.kernel.org/bpf/instruction-set.html#atomic-operations) have the following to say about that:

> Atomic operations are operations that operate on memory and can not be interrupted or corrupted by other access to the same memory region by other eBPF programs or means outside of this specification.
>
> All atomic operations supported by eBPF are encoded as store operations that use the BPF_ATOMIC mode modifier as follows:
>
> - `BPF_ATOMIC | BPF_W | BPF_STX` for 32-bit operations
> - `BPF_ATOMIC | BPF_DW | BPF_STX` for 64-bit operations
>
> 8-bit and 16-bit wide atomic operations are not supported.
>
> The ‘imm’ field is used to encode the actual atomic operation. Simple atomic operation use a subset of the values defined to encode arithmetic operations in the ‘imm’ field to encode the atomic operation:
>
> | imm | value | description |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | `BPF_ADD` | `0x00` | atomic add |
> | `BPF_OR` | `0x40` | atomic or |
> | `BPF_AND` | `0x50` | atomic and |
> | `BPF_XOR` | `0xa0` | atomic xor |
>
> `BPF_ATOMIC | BPF_W  | BPF_STX` with ‘imm’ = BPF_ADD means:
>
> ```
> *(u32 *)(dst + offset) += src
> ```
>
> `BPF_ATOMIC | BPF_DW | BPF_STX` with ‘imm’ = BPF ADD means:
>
> ```
> *(u64 *)(dst + offset) += src
> ```
>
> In addition to the simple atomic operations, there also is a modifier and two complex atomic operations:
>
> | imm | value | description |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | `BPF_FETCH` | `0x01` | modifier: return old value |
> | `BPF_XCHG` | `0xe0 | BPF_FETCH` | atomic exchange |
> | `BPF_CMPXCHG` | `0xf0 | BPF_FETCH` | atomic compare and exchange |
>
> The `BPF_FETCH` modifier is optional for simple atomic operations, and always set for the complex atomic operations. If the `BPF_FETCH` flag is set, then the operation also overwrites `src` with the value that was in memory before it was modified.
>
> The `BPF_XCHG` operation atomically exchanges `src` with the value addressed by `dst + offset`.
>
> The `BPF_CMPXCHG` operation atomically compares the value addressed by `dst + offset` with `R0`. If they match, the value addressed by `dst + offset` is replaced with src. In either case, the value that was at `dst + offset` before the operation is zero-extended and loaded back to `R0`.

These are translated into native atomic instructions during the JIT process. Here are a few links to examples of this happening for different architectures:

- https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.2.8/source/arch/arm64/net/bpf_jit_comp.c#L440
- https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.2.8/source/arch/riscv/net/bpf_jit_comp64.c#L477
- https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.2.8/source/arch/x86/net/bpf_jit_comp.c#L816

Comment: Thank you for your help, this answer perfectly sovles my problem!